# Do I need to port forward a client server in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-sockets

I am about to start creating a client server in python. Do I have to do a port forward on my router for ip and port or can i pass my data port and ip sorry for this simple question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if your router is not pointing the port 80 to your local IP, you will have to forward the port. The best way to see if it is already forwarded, use another device and try to connect to the IP by `http` (e.g. http://10.32.23.13) of your web server and you will have the confirmation if your port is forwarded or not.

Comment: So for the client I have the real outside ip and for server the ip of router or the ip of the machine?